# "mouflets" positive or negative meaning?

Tags: expressions

Just saw this word on a listening exercise on https://bitesizefrench.com/amuse-bouche/sncf-pour-nous-tous-lesson-4-et-pour-nos-mouflets/

The author seems to think its negative, I was googling but not being in country I'm curious - are they right? It may be a bit more negative?

Like the english word "brat" or "rugrat" to speak of children, as a opposed to "child" "kid". I assume not as negative as "little shit" :)

Just curious if people can shed light on this word, if I referred to another parent's child as 'son mouflet' is that negative?

Comment: *Mouflet* is **not** a negative word, and the author of this article does **not** say it has a negative meaning for them, they say "it seems it’s often translated as “brats” or in a negative way", that is not what they think and they clear agree the translation on Deepl.  But one of the sentences  is ill constructed and I suspect some words are missing. "Kid" is certainly a good translation of *mouflet*.

Answer (score 4):

***[Mouflets](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mouflet)*** is not at all negative. On the opposite it often denotes tenderness. If you look for something slightly negative, you might use ***[mioches](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mioche)***.

Here is how I would classify a few terms used to name children :

*Mouflet/Bambin/Petiot/Poupon/Pioupiou* (positive)
*Gamin/Môme/Marmot/Minot/Gone/Gosse* (neutral)
*Mioche* (slightly negative)
*Morveux* (negative)
*Merdeux* (strongly negative)

Comment: mioche n'est pas très péjoratif, non? En franchement péjoratif je voyais *morveux* ou *merdeux*.

Comment: @XouDo Oui, il y a une gradation. Je viens d'en ajouter ma perception, forcément subjective, à la réponse.

Answer (score 0):

Mouflet is not negative but as it's a word no longer used so much it can become ironic ans therefore denigrating.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *Mouflet* popularity is relatively low but it seems to have been [mostly growing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mouflets&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmouflets%3B%2Cc0) in the last 60 years.